# How do I get Prometheus to show the latest values grouped by a dimension?

Tags: prometheus

I've got a metric `service_replicas_actual`. This metric has a dimension `name`. I need a query which will group by the `name` dimension and show the most recent value.

The `name` dimension represents a Docker service, and `service_replicas_actual` keeps track of how many replicas (tasks) any given service had running at any given time. I need to create a table which will show the current number of replicas grouped by service name.

I can't really find any documentation on how I can group by dimensions and then pick the most recent value. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Turns out Prometheus does this by default. That is, it only shows the most recent value. However, Grafana would change this and by default - when creating a Table - add a timespan and look up more values. I disabled this in Grafana by setting Time Range -> Last 0s.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't really find any documentation on how I can group by dimensions and then pick the most recent value. Is there a way to do this?

There isn't, all the values came from the same scrape and are the most recent. Even if they came from different scrapes, there's still no "more recent" value as scrapes are just samples and the most recent is basically asking to randomly pick one.

If you want to `sum` or `avg` by a label you can, but a most recent aggregate doesn't make sense in a metrics-based monitoring system.